# How do you open a python file in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide

How are you supposed to open a python file in visual studio code, and by that I mean to start a new file, not open a previous one. I've been through youtube videos, downloaded python, confirmed its installed, installed the extension in VSC and set up the interpreter. But under editor, all of the videos show four buttons, one of which is like a page with a plus symbol, which is used to create a new file, so why don't I have that?

[image]

Comment: In the top menu, go `File -> New File`. If that does not exist, it may be because your workspace has not directories open (see the _NO FOLDER OPENED_ section in the explorer).

Comment: Once you create a new file, at the bottom right of the window you'll see a small area with the current language set for the file (for me it's just to the left of the bell notifications icon). For new files, by default that's "Plain Text". Click on it and select Python.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a folder opened if you want to create a new file.

Without Folder Open:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksnmp.png

With Folder Open:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBF4G.png

Comment: it looks like these images are identical

Comment: You actually don't have to have a folder open to create a new file, it's just preferred so you can specify a Python environment to use with the file.